# I don't understand is the `: MorphToMany`, line. what does it meant to have that beside a method name

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone explain to me this one. just encounter it in one of the laravel package

```
public function users(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(
        getModelForGuard($this->attributes['guard_name']),
        'model',
        config('permission.table_names.model_has_permissions'),
        'permission_id',
        'model_id'
    );
}
```

I know above is a method, but what I don't understand is the `: MorphToMany` in the line, what does it meant to have that beside a method name?

Comment: That tells PHP to expect a return value that is of type `MorthToMany`

Comment: This is a return type declaration; it says the method must return a value of type `MorphToMany` or a fatal error will be thrown. This is supported in PHP7 - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations

Comment: I see, so this will return object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a **[Return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)**:

> ...return type declarations specify the type of the value that will be returned from a function.

Another example:

```
function arraysSum(array ...$arrays): array
{
    return array_map(function(array $array): int {
        return array_sum($array);
    }, $arrays);
}
```

**Please note that this is a new feature in PHP 7**